# Google Play API

Tags: google-play, google-music

I have an artist who sells his music via google play.

I want to build software that is able to fetch data that consist of number of plays, by gender, age etc.

Is this possible? Currently I have to manually log into the website in order to retrieve the information and automation would work much better for me. 
I would be open to paying a fee as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Such an API isn't offered right now, and to be honest it seems unlikely one will be given [this page](https://play.google.com/artists/) says "If you would like to make your music available for purchase/download, we recommend one of these YouTube Preferred Partners ...".

It sounds like you'd have to write some website scraping code. There are lots of questions on stackoverflow about libraries for scraping [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is one that is commonly recommended.